# Kill commands after a command

Tags: shell-script, exit

How to kill next commands when performing a conditional loop? My condition is as below and I want to exit the whole script if it shows echo "not found" so that whatever comes after this loop won't function. Please help me. I am a total beginner in unix. Thanks.

```
if grep -q 'pattern' 'file'; 
then 
    echo "found" 
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop the commands running](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352208/how-to-stop-the-commands-running)

Comment: Did not receive any answer there. I hope I find one here.

Comment: the wrong way to get more answers is to post the question again; the right way is to update your first question in response to the clarifications

Answer (score 1):

```
if grep -q 'pattern' '/path/to/file'; 
then 
    echo "found" 
else
    echo "not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

[man exit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)

**Edit**

Alternative:

```
grep -q 'pattern' '/path/to/file'
grep_ec=$?
if [ "$grep_ec" -eq "0" ]; then 
    echo "found" 
else
    echo "not found"
    exit $grep_ec
fi
```

Comment: Was just writing this myself :]. I know you included a link to `man exit` but maybe a brief bit about why `exit 1` instead of just `exit` might be nice.

Comment: The actual exit code number depends on what you want to signal to the process invoking your script. In this case the questioner did not provide further information, so I chose 1 (catchall for general errors). You could also just forward the exit code from `grep` with: `$?`

Comment: Sorry, how to do that?

Comment: @JIGIL: I posted it as an alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `exit` command.  From `man bash`:

> exit [n]
>
> Cause the shell to exit with a status of n.  If n is omitted, the exit status is that of the last command executed.  A trap on EXIT is executed  before  the  shell  terminates.

```
if grep -q 'pattern' '/path/to/file'
then 
    echo "found" 
else
    echo "not found"
    exit
fi
```

**Note:** The semi-colon at the end of the first line is unnecessary unless you are placing additional commands afterward on the same line, e.g.

```
if grep -q 'pattern' '/path/to/file'; then
    echo "found" 
else
    echo "not found"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Sorry, one unrrelated question to my problem. How to replace '/path/to/file'? I don't want to do it manually and whenever I replace it with a command such as $PWD/filename` , it gives the error permission denied. Do you know what to do? thanks.

Comment: Since it is unrelated, it is best to ask a separate question.